# Custom scrollbar using transform and matrix3d approach

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, transform

I am trying to make a custom scrollbar using CSS **transform** and **matrix3d** approach.

```js
const scroller = document.querySelector('.container');
const thumb = document.querySelector('.box');
const scrollerHeight = scroller.getBoundingClientRect().height;
const thumbHeight = scrollerHeight * scrollerHeight / scroller.scrollHeight;
const factor = (scrollerHeight - thumbHeight) / (scroller.scrollHeight - scrollerHeight);
thumb.style.height = thumbHeight + 'px';
thumb.style.right = (scroller.clientWidth - scroller.getBoundingClientRect().width) + 'px';

thumb.style.transform = `
    matrix3d(
      1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0,
      0, 0, 0, -1
    )
    scale(${1/factor})
    translateZ(${1 - 1/factor}px)
    translateZ(-2px)
  `;
```

```css
div {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1px;
  perspective-origin: top right;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  transform-origin: top right;
  transform: matrix3d( 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1) translateZ(-2px);
  width: 20px;
}

.spacer {
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
</div>
```

Here is also a [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-nc9tfz?file=index.html)

I would like to display both vertical and horizontal scrollbars, how can I make a horizontal scrollbar in the same approach?

Comment: You could atleast provide the original source of this code:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/css-ui/custom-scrollbar.

I have also tried to achieve this in the past, but I could not find a solution. I asked a friend who understood matrix transforms and he explained that its not possible (or atleast not easy) to apply 2 transforms at the same time, so I eventually gave up.

Comment: Perhaps the upcoming scroll-animations-1 spec can help make this possible eventually. https://drafts.csswg.org/scroll-animations-1/